# When should I use NSDocument-based architecture?

Tags: cocoa

I'm kinda new to Cocoa and I find it hard to tell when to use NSDocument-based architecture vs normal NSApplication to create my application.

I'm creating these toys project to learn Cocoa:

1. To-Do list app
2. Chat program (like Adium)
3. Finance app (Simple double-entry accouting)
4. Personal bookmark app
5. CRM-like contact management

Which one of these should I make as NSDocument-based app?

I will certainly use CoreData whenever I can, but NSDocument and normal NSApplication work with CoreData so I'm not sure if this is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `NSDocument` whenever the notion of documents makes sense with your application. This is up to you to define what a document is.

An example with a todo list app:

- If you want to manage a single todo list or a single database containing several todo lists (an approach similar to iPhoto with images or iTunes with songs), then `NSApplication` is OK.
- If you want that each todo list be stored in a separate file and to be able to open several todo lists in as many windows in your application (an approach similar to TextEdit with text or Preview with images), then `NSDocument` is worth considering.

Comment: `NSApplication` and `NSDocument` aren't two different methods, approaches or objects that can't be used together. They're two completely different things: `NSDocument` is used in document-based applications and `NSApplication` is used in _every_ application. ;-)

Comment: The rest makes completely sense. :-) Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

The question to ask is not whether you should use NSDocument, but whether you intend to make a document-oriented application. Examples #1, #3, and possibly #5 are apps you could make document-centered (as opposed to library-centered).

Once you've decided whether your app uses documents, the answer to whether you should use NSDocument follows directly from that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably none.

You should use `NSDocument` if you create applications that can open multiple documents like:

- TextEdit
- Photoshop
- TextMate
- Browser
- ...